# How can I use LINQ to determine if a List<T> is a nested List

Tags: c#, list, linq, generics, nested

How can I use LINQ to determine if a `List<T>` is a nested List?

I am trying to write a generic function which will accept any `List<T>` as a parameter and do some processing on it.  Assume T is an object, and I do not pre-know the type of T, I need to examine ALL of t's members/properties, and determine if any of them is also a `List<T>` (but this time T may be any type, including the same or different as the original T) so that I can process both lists.  (Ignore any possibility of the second `List<T>` also containing a 3rd level nested list.)

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
List<List<T>> NestedList = InitialList.OfType<List<T>>().ToList();
```

but that returned 0 results.

EDIT:
I attempted this with reflection

```
public static Int32 DetermineIsNested<T>(List<T> MyList)
{
     try
     {
          if (MyList.Count > 0)
          {
               Int32 count = 0;
               foreach (PropertyInfo P in MyList[0].GetType().GetProperties())
               {
                    AddToOutput("PropertyName: " + P.Name);
                    AddToOutput("PropertyName: " + P.PropertyType);
                    if (P.PropertyType == typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<T>))
                    {
                        count++;
                        AddToOutput("MatchFound, Count++");
                    }
                }
           }

           return count;
      }
      else
      {
          AddToOutput("Error: The List Was Empty.");
          return 0;
      }
      }catch(Exception Ex)
      {
          AddToOutput("Error: " + Ex.Message);
          return 0;
      }
}
```

But I cannot get the types to match.  Because
`System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]`  does not match
`System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`

Is there a typeof() that will match all generic lists?

Comment: You will need Reflection for this.

Comment: Where are you referencing the property that you're analyzing?

Comment: in this case `NestedList` type is ``List<List<T>>`` not ``List<T>`` for the error.

Comment: What if it is an array, `LinkedList<T>`, `Queue<T>` or even just an `IEnumerable<T>`? Do you care about those types too?

Comment: the question is: even if you **could** do that, what do you want to do with the parsed object then? As you don´t know the actual type at **compile**.time, you´ll never get a **compile-time**-type. So you can´t do much with that object, unless you cast to it the type - which you don´t know at compile-time - which makes a cast impossible.

Comment: @HimBromBeere  The objects are all String data members (except for the nested list) which eventually being cast to a datatable and written to an excel column document.   If I can find the nested list, it can be processed in the same manner.   The final goal was to have all the data in the initial list on the first excel worksheet, then all the nested lists on subsequent worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

`ProprtyType` has the actual type of property, for example `List<string>` and it does not equal to `typeof(List<T>)`, you can check if `PropertyType.Name` equal to "List`1" or not. if you want to get the type of generic in PtopertyType, you can use `PropertyType.GetGenericTypeParameters`, it will return an array of types and you can check the internal generic type

```
public static Int32 DetermineIsNested<T>(List<T> MyList)
{
     try
     {
          if (MyList.Count > 0)
          {
               Int32 count = 0;
               foreach (PropertyInfo P in MyList[0].GetType().GetProperties())
               {
                    AddToOutput("PropertyName: " + P.Name);
                    AddToOutput("PropertyName: " + P.PropertyType);
                    if (P.PropertyType.Name == "List`1")
                    {
                        count++;
                        AddToOutput("MatchFound, Count++");
                    }
                }
           }

           return count;
      }
      else
      {
          AddToOutput("Error: The List Was Empty.");
          return 0;
      }
      }catch(Exception Ex)
      {
          AddToOutput("Error: " + Ex.Message);
          return 0;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[IsAssignableFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=net-5.0) may be useful here

```cs
if (typeof(List<T>).IsAssignableFrom(P.PropertyType))
```